# Removing contents from string on a imported CSV

Tags: powershell, trim

As seen below what we have is a CSV that imports into 5 columns (only the last 2 columns shown since that's where the issue is) there is more data being imported then what is needed and the data after the comma is pushing the data over into the 5th column (and beyond in instances not shown) and the system it will then be imported into will error out (red line) as seen with the red 1.

Not all the lines have multiple #'s and the #'s do vary as well. Really only need to keep the first number set IE if it reads 707,808,904 I just need the 707 everything else can be discarded and the fields that dont have the excess data obviously work fine as seen with the red 2.

Appreciate the help as always. I thought I could do it with a split or a trim but I couldnt get it to function properly and my google-fu couldn't come up with exactly what I am looking to do.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your data import settings in Excel? Please post a sample of the _raw_ CSV (open in notepad or read with `Get-Content`, then copy it [into your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64325173/edit))

Comment: you have an invalid CSV file. the multi-value items should be enclosed in quotes OR the column delimiter should be a different character.

Comment: So @MathiasR.Jessen triggered me to go take a look at my excel setting and led me down a rabbit hole where I eventually added in this line: try {$costcenter = $costcenter.replace(',',' ')} catch {write-host '$costcenter is null'} and that solved the data "bleed" into other cells issue.  Question remains if the cell has more then one set of numbers IE 760 463 562 and I only need the first set regardless of what the number is how can I do that?